# OMRON convert 16 bit numerics to ascii

Tags: plc

I am using an OMRON CJ2M PLC and writing various tag values as strings to a text file on the memory card.  For example, D100 = 65000 decimal.  Need to convert this value into its string equivalent "65000" before I can write it to the text file.  Doing numbers under 4 digits, ie 9999, I can do with various ASC and STR functions.  But once getting to over 5 decimal digits, cant figure out a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The `STR8` and `STR16` functions convert 8-digit and 16 digit hexadecimal values to their ASCII equivalents respectively. Try converting your decimal to a hex, and then use one of those functions to complete the conversion.